# How to access command line args in a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

Question: how can I access the `varargs` of the startup method inside a spring `@Bean` like MyService below?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
public MyService {
       public void run() {
               //read varargs
       }
}
```

java -jar [jarfile] **[Command Line Arguments]**

Comment: which varargs do you mean?  the arguments passed to your main class or in general any vararg?

Comment: I mean the arguments that are passed when launching the jar from command line.

Comment: how about implementing CommandLineRunner class which has a method run(String...) wher you can get hold of this varargs

Comment: This isn't what `varargs` is.  It's stuff like this: `public void foo(int ... numbers);`. The phrase  you're after is `command line arguments`.

Answer (score 12):

By analyzing spring source code, it seems that spring registers a singleton bean of type `ApplicationArguments` in the method `prepareContext` of the class `SpringApplication`

```
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("springApplicationArguments",
            applicationArguments);
```

So I think you can autowire this bean in your service :

```
@Component
public MyService {

      @Autowired
      private ApplicationArguments  applicationArguments;

      public void run() {
             //read varargs
             applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();

      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the hint of @pvpkiran:

```
@Component
public class CommandLineHolder implements CommandLineRunner {
    private String[] args;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.args = args;
    }

    public String[] getArgs() {
        return args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Configuration
public class CheckArguments {

    private ApplicationArguments applicationArguments;

    CheckArguments(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) {
        this.applicationArguments = applicationArguments;
    }

    public void printArguments(){
        for(String arg : applicationArguments.getSourceArgs()){
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `@Configuration` you should use `@Component`